# Equivalent of map struct for macOS 10.15?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-catalina, xcode12

I was following a tutorial on Xcode ([link](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views)) until I got to the "MapView" portion, at which point I was instructed to use `Map(coordinateRegion: $region)`. I am running Xcode 12.4 on a Mac Mini which can only run up to macOS 10.15, so I received the error that `'Map' is only available in macOS 11.0 or newer`. I tried browsing through the Apple documentation for equivalent code for my version of MacOS, but I was unable to find any. What equivalent code can I use to complete this portion of the tutorial?

*Full Example Code:*

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )

    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}

struct MapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try smth like `if #available(MacOS 11, *)`

Comment: If you are targeting pre macOS 11, one would create a `NSViewControllerRepresentable` with a `MKMapView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap `MKMapView` in a `NSViewRepresentable`.

The following is a barebones representation of that. Note that there's more that the SwiftUI 2.0 `Map` can do, but this will get you started with the example code you've shown:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        MapCompat(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}

struct MapCompat : NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var coordinateRegion : MKCoordinateRegion
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.region = coordinateRegion
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent : MapCompat
        
        init(_ parent: MapCompat) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.coordinateRegion = mapView.region
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Updated to fix my initial mistake of the UIKit (UIViewRepresentable) equivalent of this instead of AppKit (NSViewRepresentable)*

Comment: It says that `UIViewRepresentable` is for iOS. Do you know how I would format this code with `NSViewControllerRepresentable` instead (for macOS 10.15)?